# Unable to manage case tags

Tags: civicase, tags

Im getting this error when attempting to add tags to a case.

If I create a case and add tags at the same time, they get added.

If I subsequestly try to remove a tag, no problem.

If I subsequently try to add a tag, I get this error

```
Something wrong with getting info for tag: Expected one Tag but found 25
```

Also a huge array in the backtrace but the relevant bit I think is

```
Something wrong with getting info for tag: Expected one Tag but found 25" } ["message":protected]=> string(72) "Something wrong with getting info for tag: Expected one Tag but found 25" ["string":"Exception":private]=> string(0) "" ["code":protected]=> int(0) ["file":protected]=> string(64)
```

If I then try to view the case again, it's unviewable and has to be deleted.

Drupal up-to-date using 5.21.0

backtrace

```
CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Something wrong with getting info for tag: Expected one Tag but found 25"

#0 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php(359): civicrm_api3("entityTag", "get", (Array:6))
#1 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(595): CRM_Case_Form_CaseView->buildQuickForm()
#2 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(76): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#3 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Case_Form_CaseView), "display")
#4 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Case_Form_CaseView), "display")
#5 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(335): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#6 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php(93): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#7 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Page/Tab.php(180): CRM_Case_Page_Tab->view()
#8 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(268): CRM_Case_Page_Tab->run((Array:4), NULL)
#9 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#10 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#11 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(456): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#12 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("contact", "view", "case")
#13 /home/vwdnetor/public_html/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#14 {main}
```

Also I'm getting console error 500 on

```
/civicrm/contact/view/case?reset=1&id=859&cid=1777&action=view&context=case&selectedChild=case&key=d880725325c5ab758814d913d9a0790e_7084
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with the latest master code with either tag sets or bare tags. Are you able to reproduce on https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org? You can still post the huge backtrace - it would be helpful to see it. Also do you have any relevant extensions installed?

Comment: @demerit apols did not make it clear - don't think it's a general bug. Original question updated with backtrace and console error. Also the error log is huge rather than the backtrace

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have any customizations? I'm not sure where the phrase "Something wrong with getting info for" is coming from. Also does your line 359 in CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php match exactly up to this line or is it off by one line? https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/5.21.0/CRM/Case/Form/CaseView.php#L359

Comment: @Demerit there are extensions but all mainstream. I disabled all to check but same error. Lines up OK on 359. I'm not seeing that string anywhere either.

Comment: Hmm. Ok how about if you do `grep -r "Something wrong with getting" *` from within the civicrm folder - does it show any output?

Comment: Not even gettin anything with "Something wrong" other than a comment

Comment: Hmm. Are you set up to use an IDE/step-debugger? i.e. put a breakpoint at that line and step it through?

Comment: That phrase is in the civimobile api extension. I know you said you disabled but if you grep the folder where that extension lives does it show up? https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/blob/4.2.1/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/ApiWrapper/EntityTag/Get.php

Comment: Yep. Rock and roll. AND I didn't displabe it when checking. Thanks for perseverance. Prob solved. I'll raise it with CiviMobile.

Comment: Yay! ! ! ! ! ! !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to bet this is something to do with the civimobile api extension, even though you mentioned you tried disabling. That's the only place I can see the phrase "Something wrong with getting"

https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/blob/4.2.1/CRM/CiviMobileAPI/ApiWrapper/EntityTag/Get.php

Answer (score 2):

We have fixed the bug in last CiviMobileAPI extension (5.0.1).
Thanks for a feedback!